# How to create Entity using Hibernate to create a table with two foreign key columns: No identifier specified for entity:

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying create one table in my database that need have two foreign key columns.
but I have one exception and I don't know how to solve this error:

Could you please help me?

Exception:

No identifier specified for entity: com.xxx.client.db.domain.app.PhoneComp

Follow my Entity Class

PhoneComp.class

```
/**
 *
 * @author joh
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "phoneComp")
public class PhoneComp implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;

   @JoinColumn(name = "cellPhoneRef", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @ManyToOne
   private Cellphone cellPhoneReference;

   @JoinColumn(name = "cellPhoneComp", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @ManyToOne
   private Cellphone cellPhoneComp;

   public PhoneComp() {}

   /**get and sets*/
}
```

CellPhone.class

```
/**
 *
 * @author joh
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "cellphone")
public class Cellphone implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "cellphoneName")
    private String cellphoneName;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "isActive")
    private boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "cellphoneBrand")
    private String cellphoneBrand;

    @Column(name = "lastModifiedDate")
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    public Cellphone() {}

    /**get and sets **/

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class PhoneComp is missing a field annotated with @Id. Each @Entity needs an @Id - this is the primary key in the database.

If you don't want your entity to be persisted in a separate table, but rather be a part of other entities, you can use @Embeddable instead of @Entity.

Answer (score 1):

Your entity `PhoneComp` needs to have a primary key annotated by `@Id`.

Comment: Hi NielsNet, I added @id (I update this post) but does not working yet. I get same exception. Could you please help me understand if this id is incorrect?

Comment: @Joh hav you updated your database (if it is not done by hibernate) and restarted the application so the changes are reflected there?